# Bridj no longer working for Windows taskbar loading

Tags: java, windows, loading, taskbar, bridj

I've been using code to make the taskbar icon of my Java application have a loading bar feature which is native to `Windows 7+` applications. The code I use is the following:

```
import lombok.val;
import org.bridj.Pointer;
import org.bridj.cpp.com.COMRuntime;
import org.bridj.cpp.com.shell.ITaskbarList3;

import java.awt.*;

import static org.apache.commons.lang3.SystemUtils.*;
import static org.bridj.Pointer.pointerToAddress;
import static org.bridj.jawt.JAWTUtils.getNativePeerHandle;

public class WindowsTaskBarProgress
{
    private ITaskbarList3 taskBarList3;
    private Pointer<Integer> pointer;
    private long maximum;

    public WindowsTaskBarProgress(Component component) throws ClassNotFoundException
    {
        if (isSupportedPlatform())
        {
            taskBarList3 = COMRuntime.newInstance(ITaskbarList3.class);
            val nativePeerHandle = getNativePeerHandle(component); // <- The error arises here
            Pointer.Releaser release = pointer -> {
            };

            pointer = pointerToAddress(nativePeerHandle, Integer.class, release);
        }

        this.maximum = 100;
    }

    public void setProgressValue(long value)
    {
        if (isSupportedPlatform())
        {
            taskBarList3.SetProgressValue(pointer, value, maximum);
        }
    }

    public void resetProgress()
    {
        setProgressValue(0);
    }

    /*public void setProgressFlag(ITaskbarList3.TbpFlag flag)
    {
        if (isSupportedPlatform())
        {
            taskBarList3.SetProgressState(pointer, flag);
        }
    }*/

    private static boolean isSupportedPlatform()
    {
        return IS_OS_WINDOWS_7
                || IS_OS_WINDOWS_8
                || IS_OS_WINDOWS_10;
    }

    public void setMaximum(long maximum)
    {
        this.maximum = maximum;
    }
}
```

An [`SSCCE`](http://sscce.org) can be found [here](https://github.com/nativelibs4java/BridJ/blob/master/src/main/demos/TaskbarListDemo.java).

The `maven` dependencies I use are:

```
<!-- Windows 7+ task bar progress bar -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.nativelibs4java</groupId>
    <!-- https://github.com/nativelibs4java/BridJ -->
    <artifactId>bridj</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <!-- https://github.com/java-native-access/jna -->
    <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
    <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
    <artifactId>jna-platform</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.bridj.jawt.JawtLibrary.JAWT_GetAWT(Lorg/bridj/Pointer;Lorg/bridj/Pointer;)Z
    at org.bridj.jawt.JawtLibrary.JAWT_GetAWT(Native Method)
    at org.bridj.jawt.JAWTUtils.getJAWT(JAWTUtils.java:66)
    at org.bridj.jawt.JAWTUtils.getNativePeerHandle(JAWTUtils.java:129)
```

Note that I tried an older `JNA` version like `4.1.0` as well and it yielded the same error. What exactly broke and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow I missed the solution which was right in the example file via comment on this line:
https://github.com/nativelibs4java/BridJ/blob/master/src/main/demos/TaskbarListDemo.java#L99

Replacing the `getNativePeerHandle()` call with `getComponentID()` did the trick.

Answer (score -1):

Although there is a low probability, but I recommend adding 'jawt' dll files to on your project.

Comment: Giving more details and references is always good. otherwise you could use the comments section.

Comment: Uhh sorry! I am new this platform. Thank you for understanding.

Comment: Maybe you can use in this link .dll files. Add project reference. (https://www.dllme.com/dll/files/jawt_dll.html) If not, I'd appreciate it if you let me know. I want to help.

Comment: This did not work. You could've tried it yourself before posting an answer.